# Why it is better to avoid implicit subtype declaration in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I am getting suggestions from everywhere there we should first create subtype and then use it for variable declaration. Can anyone tell me why to avoid implicit subtype declaration?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this recommendation. Perhaps you could link to a couple of examples?

Comment: Do you mean you are string to declare a type like `type memory is array (0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)` and you get a warning? I usually get none when I do it this way.

Comment: I teach VHDL. I do not understand such a recommendation.

Comment: Define "suggestions from everywhere" and give two examples. *implicit subtype declaration* is not a term of art found in the VHDL standard (IEEE Std 1076-2008). A subtype indication defines a subtype. (6.3 Subtype declarations). Consider the only advantage to a named subtype is  where a type mark is used solely as opposed to a type mark and a constraint. These can appear in a qualified expression, a type conversion, a function return type mark, and in a signature. None of these uses dominate VHDL design descriptions.

Comment: Presumably you mean "avoid implicit declaration" without the word subtype? The only advantage would be that if you need to change the subtype (e.g. increase width) then all declarations would reflect the change, avoiding you to change all the implicit declarations.